# why top:0px not working in display :inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css

I am trying to make two div adjacently or parallel .I used **display inline-block** .It works but there is problem in that the text of second div come bottom of first div why ?

I need it should look like that [image]

I need image and description display adjacently as shown in image .but my description display bottom of image .I used **top:0px** but still no effect why ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/wZARoymFXSqXrRaH3hVn?p=preview

```
   #rightContainer{
      display: inline-block;
      width:64%;

      position:relative;
      border:1px solid ;
    }
    #textContainer{
      position:absolute;
      top:0px;
      border:1px solid blue;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` and use `vertical-align: top` for both inline-block containers:

```css
#rightContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#textContainer {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/83wDLVa7naGhhrbIrY3E?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent div instead. Remove the absolute positioning on the child div.

**Output:**

[image: Vertical Aligned]

```css
#rightContainer {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1em; /* Margin to match with left container */
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top; /* Add  to align it to top */
  width: 64%;
}
#textContainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0vRbnJomkDDDDm5OQQ06?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change to this,Also no need to change positioning here.

```
 #slideTest{
      margin-top:1em;
      border:1px solid pink;
      width:35%;
      height:100px;
      display: inline-block;
      float:left;               //CHANGE HERE
    }



    #textContainer{
      position:absolute;
      top:13px;          //HERE
      border:1px solid blue;

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just add   **position: absolute;** in #rightContainer and it will work for you and apply some **top margin** as per your thought